# Remove local Git repo when working with JGit

Tags: jgit

I am building a small tool to propose some Git commands to users not familiar with Git. The commands are not intended to modify the repo, just consult some information.
I am creating the tool in Java, using JGit which seems to be the best match to do this kind of stuff.

The issue I face so far is that I create a temporary folder to host the repo content, but I am unable to delete it automatically at the end of the execution.

Here is the code (I removed the try/catch stuff to simplify the reading):

```java
// Create temporary folder
Path folderPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File localRepoFolder = Files.createTempDirectory(folderPath, "local-repo").toFile();
// Clone the repo
CloneCommand clone = new CloneCommand();
clone.setURI("https://myrepo");
clone.setNoCheckout(true);
clone.setDirectory(localRepoFolder);
clone.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("user", "password"));
Git gitRepo = clone.call();
// Do some stuff
[...]
// Cleanup before closing
gitRepo.getRepository().close();
gitRepo.close();
localRepoFolder.deleteOnExit();
```

I searched quite a lot on this topic, but I get everywhere that it should be automatically deleted... Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the repository folder explicitly?

Comment: Yes, but it works only with a command like this:
    FileUtils.delete(localRepoFolder, FileUtils.RECURSIVE);
This does not work for a standard delete() command because this is a folder. Maybe that's the point, the deleteOnExit() just does not work on folders?

Comment: Right, `deleteOnExit()` works for files only.

Comment: Good to know! Too bad though that this is not mentioned in the Javadoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like Apache Commons IO (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) which has a `FileUtils.deleteDirectory`

Comment: I used indeed this kind of utility method (provided by jgit, but it's the same)